# `ls` error when directory is deleted

Tags: bash, filesystems, open-files, pwd

I have two shells open. The first is in directory A. In the second, I remove directory A, and then recreate it. When I go back to the first shell, and type `ls`, the output is:

```
ls: cannot open directory .: Stale file handle
```

Why? I thought the first shell (the one that remained open inside a non-existent directory) would "freeze" while waiting for the next command, and wouldn't have "realized" that the directory was deleted and recreated. Does the shell hold a "deeper" reference to its current working directory other than the string `$PWD`?

Comment: A non- answer, but if you'd simply like your shell to fall back on its feet, you can run `cd $PWD`.

Comment: I would like to understand what's going on, I know it's easy to get the shell back :)

Comment: Is this directory on an NFS server? I think that's the only situation where you get stale file handles.

Comment: The directory is local. When you do this in your system, the result is different?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A directory (like any file) is not defined by its name. Think of the name as the directory's *address*. When you move the directory, it's still the same directory, just like if you move to a different house, you're still the same person. If you remove a directory and create a new one by the same name, it's a new directory, just like someone who moves into the house where you used to live isn't you.

Each process has a [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). The `cd` command in the shell changes the shell's current working directory. The `pwd` command prints the¹ path to the current working directory.

When you removed the directory A, what this did was to remove the entry for A in its parent directory. The directory A itself remained in the filesystem, but in a detached state, with no name. It was not deleted yet because it was in use by a process, namely the first shell. When you changed the directory in the first shell, the directory was finally deleted. The same thing happens when a file is deleted while a process still has it open: the file's directory entry is removed immediately, and the file itself is removed when it stops being in use.

Similarly, observe what happens when you move directories around.

```
mkdir one two
touch one/1 two/2
cd one
ls
```

In another shell:

```
mv one tmp
mv two one
mv tmp two
```

In the first shell:

```
ls
```

The file `1` is in the directory that was originally called `one` and is now called `two`. The file `2` is in the directory that was originally called `two` and is now called `one`.

¹  <sub>More precisely, *a* path, which may not be unique if symbolic links or other subtleties are involved.</sub>

Comment: So the key point here is that a process holds the inode of its working directory, not just the path?

Comment: @Nacht The process holds a descriptor, but the kernel does all the mapping (descriptor/file tables entries/inode). And indeed, internally, the kernel does not store paths (because the interesting stuff is in the inode, not the path). Besides, a *"path"* is merely one link to a file... there may be several :)

Comment: oh right it holds a descriptor. so bash constantly holds an fd of the working directory? surely not all processes have fds of the working directory... i thought i remembered fds starting at value 3 after stdin/out/err

Comment: @Nacht The current directory isn't a file descriptor, but it works a lot like one. The kernel maintains that for every process. On Linux, you can see it in `/proc/<pid>/cwd`, which works like `/proc/<pid>/fd/<number>`. It's `CWD` in the output of `lsof`.

Comment: it is possible to make automatic `cd - && cd -` in such case?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich You could add `cd $PWD` to `preexec`, but it also means that if a directory is moved, you'd suddenly be executing commands in the new directory with the same path instead of the original directory. I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 8):

The new directory A is not the same as directory A. It can be checked with `stat` command before deleting old one and after creating new one and you will see different i-node numbers.
And I think this is related to how kernel works. It simply keeps track of the i-number of the current directory for each process. So as there are different i-numbers this will lead to different collisions.

Comment: It should be noted that an inode is a structure, not a unique number. It can be uniquely identified, but it holds more information than its ID. This is what makes it more important than links.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith I am going to delete this answer as Gilles one is better.

Comment: That's no reason to delete yours! If you feel that way, you could just add a disclaimer to your answer explaining that you consider the other one better.

Answer (score 7):

This is expected behavior. The new directory A isn't the same as the old directory A, it just happens to have the same name. So the first terminal's $PWD is still gone, it didn't magically reappear when you did the `mkdir A`.

Comment: could you elaborate on 'new directory A isn't the same as the old directory A'. What aspects of the file/directory change? Does it have to do with the inode number? Sorry to ask, but i'm just learning about this.

Comment: @rahul Philosophically, what changes is its *identity* — a new directory has been created from nothing at the same location. At an implementation level, yes, all open files are identified by inode, and the old and new directories will have distinct inodes with different inode numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A directory, like a file, has an inode associated with it:

307 % mkdir A B C

308 % ls -i 
**11997708** A  11997709 B  11997710 C

An inode is a data structure that contains information about the directory or file. Every directory and file has one. Think of it as an address (an index number really).

If I am in A, inode number **11997708** and in another shell (or in the same shell as am going to do) delete directory A then recreate it and ls the inode:

309 % cd A

310 % rmdir ../A

311 % mkdir ../A

312 % ls -i ..

**11997720** A  11997709 B  11997710 C

The i node is different, so if it try to create a file in the deleted directory A:

313 % touch this

touch: cannot touch ‘this’: No such file or directory

because the directory I am in - is no longer associated with the inode **11997720**  -  so where I currently am no longer has a legitimate address/index - inode. Thus the error.